# How to get disabled products id's and products price in magento 2 by using SQL Query?

Tags: magento2, product, price, disabled-products

I want to get disabled products id's and products price in magento 2 by using SQL Query ?

By using this i'm getting disabled product but how to get price for that products.

```
SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity_int`
WHERE attribute_id = (
SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute`
WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'status'
) AND `catalog_product_entity_int`.value = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT entity_id, value as price from catalog_product_entity_decimal
WHERE entity_id IN (SELECT entity_id FROM `catalog_product_entity_int`
WHERE attribute_id = (
SELECT attribute_id FROM `eav_attribute`
WHERE `attribute_code` LIKE 'status'
) AND `catalog_product_entity_int`.value = 2) AND attribute_id = 77;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but it gives an error on SQL " Error in query (1242): Subquery returns more than 1 row " @Natha

Comment: @Prits Edited. Fixed. please try the latest query now.

Comment: and let me know if it's working for you or not.

Comment: Yes it shows the result but showing the result i have attached screenshot in question showing two entity_id but the first one has the the actual price what is second row is fetched @Natha

Comment: do you have multiple stores?

Comment: please add 'store_id' after 'as price' in the first line of query and see the results and see if it's different or the same.

Comment: No there is only one store in the system @Natha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112144/discussion-between-prits-and-natha-odedara).

Comment: yes sure, do check msgs there.